# Can't import matplotlib under Ipython notebook anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have downloaded and installed anaconda. But when I run jupyter notebook and import matplotlib , it doesn't work. Below are some commands

`which -a python`

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

`which -a jupyter`

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

I run the notebook as follows

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the below error

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fe07c3ebfee7> in <module>()
      2 # before proceeding further.
      3 from __future__ import print_function
----> 4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import os

ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Note when I run python through terminal I can import matplotlib , the problem only persist in the browser of ipython notebook after running jupyter.

Comment: What does the output from `sys.path` show for the terminal, and the notebook?

Comment: Does other packages works well. I think there may be two reasons. First, you start up a wrong kernel corresponding to the Python version which works well in terminal. Second, the system path of Anaconda may be wrong. You can try `conda install matpllotlib`.

Comment: Yes , when I print sys.path , Ipython version prints /usr/lib/python3.5 , but the terminal prints /home/user/anaconda3 . How do fix Ipython to use anaconda one ? I am running jupyter from anaconda installation , why it is referring to the /usr/lib python??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after changing `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` . 
The path there was /usr/bin/python , changed it to anaconda one.